# Iterating over objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have an obejct of the form:

```
var test = {"2011":{"10":4,"9":9,"8":15,"7":11,"6":11,"5":13,"4":9,"3":5,"2":9,"1":4,"0":20},"2010":{"11":9,"10":23,"9":58}}
```

I want to iterate over this so I can hit each year and month combo.  I have:

```
var years = d3.keys(test),
    months = d3.range(12),
    data = [];
```

So, as a Javascript newbie, to sanity check things I inspect `years`.

```
document.writeln(years)
2011,2010
```

Cool, but when I try to iterate over the `years` array to pull data out of `test` the elements I do what I think is correct to test, but the elements are lost:

```
for(var y in years) {
  document.writeln(y);
}
0,1
```

How do I iterate over `years` to get the actual elements (`2011,2010`) in them?

Comment: I see no JSON, which is a text-based data interchange format, here. And please prefer the term "object" over "[associative] array" to avoid dangerous confusion.

Comment: Use console.log or an actual debugger instead of document.write. Also. for $diety's sake, someone write an answer that doesn't incentivize using for-in to loop in an array.

Comment: Where is the array? I don't see one.

Comment: I know it's technically correct to do so, but if I see one more comment like "that's not JSON, that's an object", or something similar, I may just have to stick a knife in something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`for in` retrieves indices/keys (not the values).**

You'll need to modify your loop, like so:

```
for(var y in years) {
  document.writeln(years[y]);
}
```

**EDIT** - per missingno's comment, iterating over an array using `for in` is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays).

```
for(var i = 0, l = years.length; i < l; i++) {
  document.writeln(years[i]);
}
```

A little extra information... if you use a for/in loop against an object it will also iterate over your property keys.  For example,

```
for(var y in test) {
  //This will yield, "2011" and then "2010"
  document.writeln(y);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to just access the elements with reference the array, like I would with for-loop over an iterator in Python?

Comment: @DrewConway what you are looking for is [`for each`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) for iterating over object property values, but it's non-standard and not widely available. If you want to iterate over arrays, then check out [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: I personally recommend [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) as a bridge for functions like `forEach` that aren't widely supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript `for in` loops don't do what you think they do; they give you the keys, not the elements

You want

```
for(var y in years) {
  document.writeln(years[y]);
}
```

Since you're getting 0,1 back, it looks like years is an actual array, so you could also simply do

```
for(var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(years[i]);
}
```

Also, you already edited your title, but a note on terminology.  If it's a string, then it's JSON.  If it's an object, then, well, it's an object.  There's no such thing as a "json object" or "json array"

Comment: Thanks for the clarity.  I suffer the ignorance of interacting with JSON primary outside of Javascript.

Comment: @Drew - no worries.  I used to call it a json object all the time until someone on SO corrected me :)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `var y in years` will give you the *keys* to the array `years`.  `years[y]` should give you the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

y will end up being the index by which you access the elements in years which is 0 and 1 (because years is an array).  So for accessing the values of years, try using

```
writeln(years[y])
```

instead of

```
writeln(y)
```

(IMHO, Javascript is a bit counter intuitive by working this way)