# Iterating object objects correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, foreach

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}    

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(x){
    console.log(obj[x])
})
```

This gives: 1 2 3

so how can I make it to work give me 1 4 9 (e.g. times by itself) I thought this would work

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(x){
    console.log(obj[x*x])
})
```

Comment: why dont you use array???

Comment: that would try to take the ninth value, try something like `obj[x]*obj[x]`

Comment: use [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) `console.log(Math.pow(obj[x], 2));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over objects in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389148/iterating-over-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to multiply the values.

you have `x*x` which would be `'a'*'a'` results in `NaN`.

```
obj[NaN] = undefined
```

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(x){
    console.log(obj[x] * obj[x])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
this one does the job:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(x){
    console.log(obj[x]*obj[x])
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) in ES2016

```
Object.values(obj).forEach(function(x){
   console.log(x*x);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c:3}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(x){
    console.log(Math.pow(obj[x], 2));
})
```

Math.pow (x,y) => x*x*x*...y times...*x